# How can I stop /cancel specific pendingintent for this code?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am scheduling multiple intents to be send to a `BroadcastReceiver`. The difference between every intent is the time when it will be received and extra data it contains.
Now I need to cancel the specific pending intent.

This is the code for `SetAlarm()` method:

```
int mrng_hour = Integer.parseInt(ls.get(i).getSch_mrng_hour());
int mrng_mins = Integer.parseInt(ls.get(i).getSch_mrng_mins());
Calendar mrng_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mrng_calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mrng_hour);
mrng_calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mrng_mins);
mrng_calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Intent in = new Intent(context, Alarmclass.class); in .putExtra("mid", req_CODE);
PendingIntent mrng_pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, req_CODE, in , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mgrAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mrng_calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mrng_pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create same pendingintent again and cancel it. `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);`

Comment: thank you for your reply...but i was tried alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);,it also not working... :(

Comment: how to i stop previous pendingintent?